# How to install Filder on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu

How to install Filder on Ubuntu 11.10 ?
Or can someone suggest me other software, I need to monitor TCP from just one IP address.

Comment: When you say "Filder", do you mean "[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)"?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor TCP packets arriving at my computer from one source address I would use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

```
 tcpdump host foo
```

To view HTTP requests and responses I would prefer to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)'s "[follow tcp stream](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html)" feature. You can probably install it using `apt-get wireshark` or by [using Synaptic](http://blog.sudobits.com/2010/06/23/how-to-install-wireshark-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

Comment: Wireshark is useful, but for day-to-day HTTP debugging, I find it too low-level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really. What I did was to install Virtualbox, and make a WinXP virtual machine in it. I run Fiddler there, and connect to it as to a normal proxy, from the host computer. This has the extra requirement of a Windows license, but It Works.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617536/http-debugging-proxy-for-linux-and-mac , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355320/is-there-a-standard-alternative-to-fiddler-fiddler2-for-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2

Comment: Update: there is now an experimental Linux build at http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono